# jQuery fade in image not responding

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using query / ajax to validate a login.  When the login submit is pressed, the function is called.

For the second or two that validation takes I'd like a gif to be displayed but my code isn't working.  The path of image is correct, I've tried absolute just to rule out.  I also tried removing the fadeIn and adding random text inside the .html() but still nothing.

What am I missing? I can't frown at it any more! :)

Bulk of the function.
worth noting that the 'checking...' is displayed. (could this be overwriting the image?)

```
var params = {username: username, password: password};
var url = "../loginProcessAjax.php";

$("#statusLogin").show();
$("#statusLogin").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="../images/loading.gif" />');

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: params,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        document.getElementById("statusLogin").innerHTML= 'checking...' ;
    },

    success: function(data) {
```

EDIT: So it turns out that commenting the 'checking...' line allowed the image to be displayed.  Can this be explained please and how might I get them both to be displayed together?

Answer (score 1):

Nailed it:)

```
beforeSend: function() {
          document.getElementById("statusLogin").innerHTML= '<img src="../images/loading.gif" /> checking...' ;
        },
```